# Geth transactions not broadcast and stuck in pending state

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, private-blockchain, pending-transactions, geth-debugging

Setup three Geth private network nodes(Clique) via docker container. They are deployed on three different VMs. Among 3 nodes, there is a miner node to mine the block, a RPC node to accept RPC request, and a boot peer node to connect both of them. This boot node connect to miner and RPC node peer by peer while RPC and miner node has no directly connection.

Sometimes when there are transactions, they are stuck in pending state and never broadcast. This situation happens randomly, sometimes the transactions can be mined by miner but sometimes they just stuck in pending transaction.

There is no problem with the gas and the nonce. Also, if I connect my RPC node to miner node by admin.addPeer(), then this situation totally disappear and everything become normal. The question seems to be the RPC node sometimes does not broadcast my transactions if it does not connect to a miner directly.

Another situation worth mentioning: the blocks can sync within the private network, get the same number when eth.blockNumber, but sometimes RPC node may sync slow, for example the miner has now mined 100 blocks, and the RPC may only sync to 80 blocks while eth.syncing returns false, although finally it will catch up with the block, it sometimes lag behind the miner.

System information
Geth version: Geth/v1.11.6
OS & Version: Ubuntu 22.04
Miner start commands:
--nodekey=miner.key
--bootnodes="enode://${BOOTNODE_KEY}@${BOOTNODE_IP}:${BOOTNODE_PORT}"
--syncmode=full
--gcmode=archive
--miner.etherbase=${ADDR}
--mine
--miner.threads=1
--networkid=${NETWORK_ID}
--unlock=${ADDR}
--password=password
--allow-insecure-unlock
--verbosity=5
RPC start commands:
--nodekey=rpc.key
--bootnodes="enode://${BOOTNODE_KEY}@${BOOTNODE_IP}:${BOOTNODE_PORT}"
--syncmode=full
--gcmode=archive
--networkid=${NETWORK_ID}
--http
--http.vhosts=""
--http.addr="0.0.0.0"
--http.port=8545
--http.corsdomain=""

Expected behaviour
Transactions are successfully broadcasted and mined.

Actual behaviour
Transaction sometime not broadcast within the private network.
txpool of RPC
txpool.inspect
{
pending: {
0x55FAac070a63F809eDF68D72856Ea88c183171C8: {
0: "contract creation: 0 wei + 5171633 gas × 2000000000 wei",
1: "contract creation: 0 wei + 4398916 gas × 2000000000 wei",
2: "contract creation: 0 wei + 5131938 gas × 2000000000 wei"
}
},
queued: {}
}

txpool of miner and boot node

txpool.inspect
{
pending: {},
queued: {}
}

I have posted the same issue on Github issue:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/28518
Also, I think my issue is very similar to
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/22308#issuecomment-781940794

Answer (score 0):

It is my experience - see [1] - that the node discovery is by default disabled on a private network (if the bootnode runs with the `--nodiscover` flag). The behavior is not documented but it seems that the `--nodiscover` flag is passed along to all nodes connected to the bootnode so they will not "discover" or to each other and thus the tx from the RPC never reach the miner.

The only way I've been able to reliably get the miner to get the tx from the rpc was to connect the two via either static or trusted nodes

[1] - [Private network nodes can't find peers](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/121380/private-network-nodes-cant-find-peers) <- see also the SE posts regarding this topic listed there